# How to restrict the amount of categories/post tags/terms for a post type post

Tags: categories, metabox, users

I'm in need of a solution that allows me to restrict the user/author to only use maximum of two categories per new post. One post can only have one or two categories.

The only similar solution that I have found is when you make the categories as radio buttons instead of check boxes. But that will restrict the user to choose only one category.
[Only one category per post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/only-one-category-per-post)

Any idea have to solve this?

Comment: Do you have any idea what to do when the user chooses too many categories? Let's assume that JavaScript is turned off by the user and he selects 5 instead of 2 categories. What _exactly_ would you do? Remove all cats? Only 3? If so: Which ones? What would you tell the user and where?

Comment: I believe (s)he wants a JavaScript snippet that counts the number of selected cats/tags and alerts the users they can't check the third when they try to, so the user has to choose the 2 cats/tags. Unfortunately, this is not a snippet shop. It's a place for learning. We can help you spot the bugs in your code @Flumra. Now, where exactly is your code? [ And I also believe (s)he never thought users can turn javascript off. :) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks the the replies.
I solved my problem with jQuery.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("#category-tabs li.hide-if-no-js").hide(); //Hides Most Used tab

$("#category-all input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var max = 2; // Max allowed cats
    var count = $("#category-all input:checked").length; //counts selected cats
    if (count > max) {
        $(this).prop("checked", "");
        alert('You are only allowed to select ' + max + ' categories.'); //alert message when user tries to select a third cat
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: which is only a solution for the post edit page, but will not solve the problem for quick edit or editing via the smartphone apps (in other words changes done via xml-rpc).

Comment: Quick edit can also be solved with jQuery and thanks for the tip on the xml-rpc related problems.

Comment: Nice but is there any option to restrict to use not more than 3 tag